# Spring batch 1 million records - 5 hours

Tags: spring-batch

Is it normal if 1 million IDs from a table are read using JdbcCursorItemReader and written to a file using FlatFileItemWriter and the process takes 5 hours?

Spring suggests using JdbcCursorItemReader for improving performance and I have already used that. What else can be done?

Can I skip the row mapper altogether as I am converting ID fetched to a Map entry (Map) in the mapper and fetching the ID from the Map while writing which seems useless.

Is Spring batch the ideal approach for such scenarios?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Should I post to the Spring community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added commitInterval property and set it's value to 10,000. The process now completes in 44 mins. Thanks.